# Maven looking for dependency in wrong repo

Tags: java, maven

I have a snapshot maven repo defined:

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>tmp-repo</id>
        <url>https://my-snapshot-repo</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
            <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

The problem is, for some reason, maven is looking for the following two dependencies:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpcomponents-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpcomponents-client</artifactId>
        <version>4.4</version>
    </dependency>
```

In the snapshot repo rather than the stable maven repo. Each compile gives this error:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project myProject: Could not resolve
>   dependencies for project com.myGroupId:myArtifact:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT:
>   The following artifacts could not be resolved:
>   org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcomponents-core:jar:4.4,
>   org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcomponents-client:jar:4.4: Could not
>   find artifact org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcomponents-core:jar:4.4 in
>   tmp-repo (https://my-snapshot-repo)

How do I force maven to not look for this dependency in the snapshot repo?

Answer (score 1):

Before your edit, your original configuration said:

```
    <releases>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
    </releases>
```

You said that this repo holds releases, as well as snapshots, so Maven is looking there.

Now you've removed `<releases>`, it shouldn't be doing that. Make sure you don't have any other repository definitions taking effect.

Comment: I've removed that, so now it only holds `<snapshots>`, but i'm still getting the same error.

Comment: Also, I have quite a few other dependencies, but its only failing to find this particular dependency.

Comment: In answer to your edit.. that's the only repository i have defined.